# Custom Object List To JSON And Back To Custom Object List C#

Tags: c#, json, formatting

I have a custom object that looks like this:

```
 public class myObject
{
public string address;
public int port;
}
```

I have a list of "myObject". I then want to make the list of myObjects and convert it to JSON formating with JSON.net. I then Want to be able to Convert it back into a List of myObject. Simply using SerializeObject and DeserializeObject doesn't seem to do the trick.
Happy for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple, using JSON.NET ( http://www.newtonsoft.com/ )

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<myObject>() { new myObject() {address="address", port=11}};

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);

    var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<myObject>>(json);
}

public class myObject
{
    public string address;
    public int port;
}
```

Comment: Well, the var deserialized isn't a "myObject". That's the issue Im having.

Comment: Or actually. Let me clearify. I am unsure where the issue arrives. But the issue im having with what you provided above is the following:

Comment: My custom oject looks like this:

Comment: Sorry for all this spam. I am fairly new to this site. How do I make comments that are long with actual line breaks? My issue is that it doesnt properly come back to an object. When I deserialize it and try to access something in the deserialized object it doesnt actually return what its supposed to.

Comment: You can update your question with sample code which does not working. Right now Im not sure that I can understand what exactly your problem is